# stay in dashboard when the user is logged

Tags: php, codeigniter

how can I stay in dashboard when the user is logged even though when the user write localhost/storeLTE/login/ then stay home. but my code doesnt work.

```
public function getAccess(){
            if ($this->session->set_userdata('username')) {
                redirect('home');
            }
            $username = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('username'));
            $password = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('password'));
            $array = $this->User_model->login($username,$password);
            if($array[0] == 0){
                echo 0;
            }else{
                $data_session = array(
                    'id' => $array[0]['iduser'],
                    'username' => $array[0]['username'],
                    'password' => $array[0]['password'],
                    'name' => $array[0]['name'],
                    'last_name' => $array[0]['last_name'],
                    'type' => $array[0]['idType'],
                    'logged_in' => TRUE
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata('log',$data_session);
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you met problem with unset. use $this->session->sess_destroy();

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($this->session->set_userdata('username')) {
```

should be

```
if ($this->session->userdata('username')) {
```

or

```
if ($this->session->userdata('username') !== NULL) {
//since NULL is returned if item is not found
```

[Docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#retrieving-session-data).

Comment: or how can I intragete my code for if-else if -else? the same way or do I have to change a lot =?

Comment: I am not sure regarding the rest of your code, but I could propose you well writen authentication called "ion auth".

Answer (score 1):

[FYI](https://www.google.lk/search?q=FYI&oq=FYI&aqs=chrome..69i57.739j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=fyi%20meaning)

**Its is NOT a good sign of STORING PASSWORD IN THE SESSION. Its better to store `name`, `type`, `logged_in`, `id`.**

---

**In Controller**

```
function getAccess(){

    $this->load->library('session'); # load library here or in autoload.php

    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == TRUE) 
    {
        redirect('home');
    }
    else
    {
        $username = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('username'));
        $password = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('password'));

        $result = $this->User_model->login($username,$password);
        if($result == FALSE)
        {
            echo 'Invalid Login';
        }
        else{
            $data_session = array(
                'id' => $result[0]['iduser'],
                'username' => $result[0]['username'],  # Better to remove
                'password' => $result[0]['password'], # Better to remove
                'name' => $result[0]['name'],
                'last_name' => $result[0]['last_name'],
                'type' => $result[0]['idType'],
                'logged_in' => TRUE
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata('log',$data_session);

            $this->load->view('home'); # Load the view
        }
    }

}
```

**In Model**

```
function login($username,$password)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table name WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'");
    $result = $query->result_array();

    if (count($result) > 1 || empty($result)) 
    {
        return FALSE;
    } 
    else {
        return $result;
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  if ($this->session->set_userdata('username')) {
                redirect('home');
            }
```

change this to

```
  if ($this->session->userdata('username') !='') {
                redirect('home');
            }
```

Comment: You are setting the username instead of, checking the username.